# My Dropdown Navigation Bar Will Not Go In Front Of Text

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu, navigationbar

**Hello**,

I have been making a website recently and I was making a dropdown navigation bar. The thing is, whenever I insert text and hover over my navigation bar, it does not cover the text. I have searched along Stack Overflow for a little bit now, and everything I've tried hasn't worked. I have tried "position: absolute;", "z-index: 1000;" etc. I was wondering if I made my own forum, someone could possibly help me out. Internet Explorer, Google Chrome, and Microsoft Edge all do not work. Thank you for responding.

```css
/*Title*/

html, body {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 font-family: Cursive, Sans-Serif;
}

#header {
 width: auto;
 height: 10px;
 padding: 1% 1% 1% 2%;
 background-color: #5e0d0d;
 box-shadow: 1px 1px 2px 2px #262626;
}

#header #title {
 font-family: "Open Sans", "Segoe UI";
 font-size: 150%;
 font-weight: lighter;
 color: #fff;
 text-decoration: none;
 float: left;
 margin-top: -.65%;
}

/*Navigation Bar*/

ul {
 font-family: Arial;
 margin: 0px;
 padding: 0px;
 list-style: none;
}

ul li {
 float: left;
 width: 200px;
 height: 40px;
 line-height: 40px;
 text-align: center;
 font-size: 20px;
 margin-top: -.60%
}

ul li a {
 text-decoration: none;
 color: white;
 display: block;
}

ul li a:hover {
 background-color: #911515;
 z-index: 1000;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <title>Slasher Hub - Latest</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width:device-width; initial-scale:1;">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
 </head>
 
 <body>
  <header id="header">
   <a href="index.html" id="title">Slasher Hub</a>
   <nav>
    <ul>
     <li style="margin-left: 40px;"><a>Home</a></li>
     <li><a>About Me</a></li>
     <li><a>Slasher Dev Team</a>
      <ul>
       <li><a>About Us</a></li>
       <li><a>Contact</a></li>
       <li><a>News</a></li>
       <li><a>Recent</a></li>
      </ul>
     </li>
     <li><a>Gallary</a></li>
    </ul>
   </nav>
  </header>
  <h3>Welcome to the Slasher Hub! This is the latest stuff going on with Slasher now!</h3>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Are you using any library to generate the nav bar?

Comment: Using ids for styling is going to bite you at some point. Use classes instead

Answer (score 0):

To make z-index work you have to add `position:absolute` to the element.

```
ul li a:hover {
background-color: #911515;
z-index: 1000; 
position: absolute; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Overall, all you had to do was add `position: relative` to either your `<nav>` or `<header>` element.

```css
/*Title*/

html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: Cursive, Sans-Serif;
}

#header {
  width: auto;
  height: 10px;
  padding: 1% 1% 1% 2%;
  background-color: #5e0d0d;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 2px 2px #262626;
}

#header #title {
  font-family: "Open Sans", "Segoe UI";
  font-size: 150%;
  font-weight: lighter;
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
  float: left;
  margin-top: -.65%;
}


/*Navigation Bar*/

ul {
  font-family: Arial;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  list-style: none;
}

ul li {
  float: left;
  width: 200px;
  height: 40px;
  line-height: 40px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 20px;
  margin-top: -.60%
}

ul li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
  display: block;
}

ul li a:hover {
  background-color: #911515;
  z-index: 1000;
}

/* Here's the change */
header {
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Slasher Hub - Latest</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width:device-width; initial-scale:1;">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>
  <header id="header">
    <a href="index.html" id="title">Slasher Hub</a>
    <nav>
      <ul>
        <li style="margin-left: 40px;"><a>Home</a></li>
        <li><a>About Me</a></li>
        <li><a>Slasher Dev Team</a>
          <ul>
            <li><a>About Us</a></li>
            <li><a>Contact</a></li>
            <li><a>News</a></li>
            <li><a>Recent</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a>Gallary</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </header>
  <h3>Welcome to the Slasher Hub! This is the latest stuff going on with Slasher now!</h3>
</body>

</html>
```

I also modified your `<nav>` menu a bit to give you some ideas of an overall setup.

```css
/*Title*/

html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: Cursive, Sans-Serif;
}

#header {
  width: auto;
  /* height: 10px; Remove the height */
  display: inline-block; /* Set the display */
  padding: 1% 1% 1% 2%;
  background-color: #5e0d0d;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 2px 2px #262626;
}

#header #title {
  font-family: "Open Sans", "Segoe UI";
  font-size: 150%;
  font-weight: lighter;
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
  float: left;
  margin-top: -.65%;
}


/*Navigation Bar*/

/* Make the position of the container relative to have it sit above the content */
nav {
  position: relative;
}

/* Add nav to each of the navigation bar selectors to be more specific */
nav ul {
  font-family: Arial;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  list-style: none;
}

nav ul li {
  float: left;
  width: 200px;
  height: 40px;
  line-height: 40px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 20px;
}

nav li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
  display: block;
}

nav li:not(.top-level) a {
  background-color: #5e0d0d;
}
nav li:not(.top-level) a:hover {
  background-color: #911515
}

nav li.top-level > ul {
  display: none;
}

nav li.top-level:hover > ul {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<header id="header">
  <a href="index.html" id="title">Slasher Hub</a>
  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li class="top-level"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
      <li class="top-level"><a href="#">About Me</a></li>
      <li class="top-level"><a href="#">Slasher Dev Team</a>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">About Us</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">News</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Recent</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li class="top-level"><a href="#">Gallary</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</header>

<h3>Welcome to the Slasher Hub! This is the latest stuff going on with Slasher now!</h3>
```

Let me know if you have any questions.